# DC/OS stateful app with persistent external storage

Tags: amazon-ec2, mesosphere, dcos

I'm trying to setup a stateful app in DC/OS by assigning an external (EBS) volume to the docker container. I've ran the demo app provided in the docs and it created a 100GB EBS volume in AWS. Is there a way to specify the size of the volume in the `marathon.json` file? Can I use the same EBS volume for multiple apps? Here's the demo app I've tested.

```
{
  "id": "/test-docker",
  "instances": 1,
  "cpus": 0.1,
  "mem": 32,
  "cmd": "date >> /data/test-rexray-volume/test.txt; cat /data/test-rexray-volume/test.txt",
  "container": {
    "type": "DOCKER",
    "docker": {
      "image": "alpine:3.1",
      "network": "HOST",
      "forcePullImage": true
    },
    "volumes": [
      {
        "containerPath": "/data/test-rexray-volume",
        "external": {
          "name": "my-test-vol",
          "provider": "dvdi",
          "options": { "dvdi/driver": "rexray" }
        },
        "mode": "RW"
      }
    ]
  },
  "upgradeStrategy": {
    "minimumHealthCapacity": 0,
    "maximumOverCapacity": 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot attach one EBS volume to multiple EC2 instances. My bad! I ditched the rexray persistent storage option in favor of EFS.

I had to create an EFS share and attach it to the cluster's VPC. Then I had to ssh into every slave node, mount it like an NFS share under the same folder on all nodes and finally mount it in the container from marathon.json.